# What is the best way to return multiple variables and arrays formatted in xml, json etc with respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I'm looking for a good way to return xml or json from a controller *including* multiple variables. For example:

```
def index
    @ad = Ad.some_annoying_ad
    @map = Map.some_map_for_something
    @articles = Articles.trending

    respond_with @articles
end
```

How would I best add the @ad and @map var to the @articles array? I have seen people using the merge function, but I am not sure if that's what I'm looking for. Just want to know which way is most standard, flexible, DRY. Thanks!

Note: I am aware that respond with will automatically format the results in xml or json depending on the file extension added to the url. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of merging @ad, @map, just create create a new hash then put add the arrays to it, like

```
respond_with({:ad => @ad, :map => @map, :article => @article})
```

It just render all the datas with groups.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to take a look at RABL (stands for Ruby API Builder Language) gem ([cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl), [github](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/)). It offers you a DSL for defining the structure of your JSON/XML response in templates (like Haml or CoffeeScript does).

In your case it can be like this:

```
# in *.json.rabl or *.xml.rabl

object false
child(@ad) { attributes :field1, :field2 }
child(@map) { attributes :field3, :field4 }
child(@article) { attributes :body => :content } # remap is easy!
```

There is even partials support for DRYing your code. Worth trying.